# both (WAS) and (W3SVC) stopped in iis

Tags: iis, web, was

[image]

I cant start my site in IIS after restarting windows server 2012, because both of  (WAS) and  (W3SVC) stopped.

how fixed them.

by the way i used "net start W3SVC" in CMD, but nothing changed.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Just go to services and click on World  wide web publishing services was disabled and change to automatically, in same dialogue box you can see Log On button and click the button and click on Allow services, and restart your machine.

Comment: It was not exactly the same procedure for me, but after starting World wide web publishing services problem solved. BTW you need to refresh the IIS websites tree root to able to start sites again

Answer (score 2):

IIS depends on the World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC) which in-turn depedns on the Windows process Activation Service (WAS). So you need to start both the services before IIS can be started.

You can do this either by using the net start command or by manually going to the services.msc.

In your case net start W3SVC did not work as W3SVC needs WAS to be in running state. So WAS service needs to be started first.

Use the following command to start the services (you may need to run command prompt as admin)

```
NET START WAS
NET START W3SVC
```

Alternatively - go to run and type services.msc Scroll down till you get Windows Process Activation Service and start it. Then scroll further down to World Wide Web Publishing Service and start that.

Finally start your IIS (for instance use IISRESET command)